# Articles about Javascript security

Tags: javascript, article, javascript-security

I'm searching fundamentals of Javascript Security and its weaknesses. I'm already reading Javascript: The Complete Rereference 2nd Edition. I'm looking for good articles. Any suggestions, please? Thanks.

Comment: Funny guys. I know what a search engine is. I don't need anonymous information, I need referenced articles based on documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the book Head First Javascript...its better than complete reference and also will give you what you want...